# How do i execute a production build with ng2-redux and @select?

Tags: angular, redux, angular-cli

I'm currently using ng2-redux to access global state in my application. I use DI to access that Observable. This all works fine with JIT, but when i execute an AOT buuild i get the following error:

```
ng build --environment=prod --target=production
```

*ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 25:11 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol AdminComponent in /Users/jmurphy/projects/fish/tank/src/app/admin/admin.component.ts*

I've been using the following pattern in all of my components to inject the Observables:

```
  @select((state: IAppState) => state.lens) public readonly remoteLens$: Observable<IRemoteObject<LensDTO>>;
  @select((state: IAppState) => state.admin) public readonly remoteAdmin$: Observable<IRemoteObject<AdminDTO>>;
```

**What is the correct pattern to use to allow Type Safe access of the global state through out my application and bypass the build error?**

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for:

```
export function selectBaseId(appstore) {
  return appStore.base.id;
}

class YourClass {
  // ...
  @select(selectBaseId) routeId$: Observable<number>;
}
```

or with a selector:

```
export function selectBaseId(appstore) {
  return appStore.base.id;
}

class YourClass {
  // ...
  @select(['base', 'id']) routeId$: Observable<number>;
}
```

From angular-redux issue: https://github.com/angular-redux/store/issues/236

Comment: That does work. But that's ridiculous syntax. This looks like a bug.